# When is it necessary to specific application/json Content-Type explicitly

Tags: android, python, rest

Currently, I'm building a Android mobile app & Python restful server services.

I found that, it makes no different, whether or not I'm using

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
```

The following code (which doesn't specific Content-Type explicitly) works fine for me. I was wondering, in what situation, I should specific **Content-Type** explicitly?

---

### Python restful server services code

```
class DebugHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        response = {}
        response["key"] = "value"
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response))

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/debug', DebugHandler),
], debug = True)
```

---

### Android mobile app client code

```
public static String getResponseBodyAsString(String request) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(request);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        initHttpURLConnection(httpURLConnection);
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        int charRead = 0;
        char[] buffer = new char[8*1024];
        // Use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer. We do not concern
        // on thread safety. stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((charRead = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            stringBuilder.append(buffer, 0, charRead);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    } finally {
        close(bufferedReader);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: There is a mist around this method, I have used it in one of my projects without using url.openConnection()....it works. Would love if someone comes up with a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Content-Type` specifies what's inside the response (i.e. how to interpret the body of the response). Is it JSON, a HTML document, a JPEG, etc? It is useful when you have different representations of your resources and together with `Accept` it's a header involved in doing [content negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) between client and server.

Different clients might need different formats. A C# client might prefer XML, a Javascript client might prefer JSON, another client could work with multiple representations but try to request the most efficient one first and then settle for others if the server can't serve the preferred one, etc.

`Content-Type` is very important in the browser so that the user agent knows how to display the response. If you don't specify one the browser will try to guess, usually based on the extension and maybe fallback to some `Save as...` dialog if that fails also. In a browser, the lack of a `Content-Type` might cause some HTML to open a `Save as...` dialog, or a PDF file to be rendered as gibberish in the page.

In an application client, not having a `Content-Type` might cause a parsing error or might be ignored. If you server only serves JSON and your client only expects JSON then you can ignore the `Content-Type`, the client will just assume it's JSON because that's how it was built.

But what if at some point you want to add XML as a representation, or YAML or whatever? Then you have a problem because the client assumed it's always JSON and ignored the `Content-Type`. Now when it receives XML it will try to parse as JSON and fail. If instead the client was built with content types in mind and you always specify a `Content-Type` then your client will then take it into account and select an appropriate parser instead of blindly making assumptions.